# Downloading files from java bean only works once

Tags: java, filesystems, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a java bean which I use to download files from the server.

```
public void download(String filePath) throws IOException {

    try {
        String fn = new File(filePath).getName();
        byte[] data = grabFile(filePath);
        XspHttpServletResponse response = (XspHttpServletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
        response.setContentType(URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fn));
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fn);
        OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
        output.write(data);
        output.close();

    }catch(Exception e) {

    }finally {

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete(); 
    }
}
```

I can call this bean from a link on my xpage using the following SSJS code, I am using full refresh in the link.

```
var dw = new FileShare();
dw.download("c:\test\filename.docx")
```

The code works fine, the file is downloaded from the server at the location when I click the link but it only works the first time. If I reload the whole page using the browser refresh button I can download another file.

How can I fix this code so that I can click to download from all links I have on my xpage without reloading the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use XSP.allowSubmit() in your link.

Check Per Henrik Lausten answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930956/poi-4-xpages-document-generation-works-only-once)  (the one validated) for more details

Renaud