# How to return PDF file after xpage submission properly? First submission make app stop working in browser

Tags: xpages

I have a simple request for Xpages app. I have calculator like page where user enters some data and after submission (button action with full submit e,g, 'Export to PDF' button) app should create PDF and return back to browser. Everything is actualy working fine for me except that this works first time only. It returns PDF back to browser but then browser page stops working ... buttons or ajax partial refreshes dont work anymore. I understand its related to fact that browser submits data to server and expects payload come back but instead I'm sedning PDF file but how to handle it different way? I need the page submit because I'm managing the viewState for page that is necessery for me when rendering PDF content ... Any idea how to solve it properly?

Here is my code I'm using for sending PDF back to browser.

```
ExternalContext exCon = DominoAccess.getFacesContext().getExternalContext();        
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)exCon.getResponse();
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename="+fileName);
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

//Get the document out to the screen
createPdf(out,html);

// Stop the page from further processing;
DominoAccess.getFacesContext().responseComplete();
```

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21931903/785061

Comment: possible duplicate of [POI 4 XPages - document generation works only once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930956/poi-4-xpages-document-generation-works-only-once)